# Cant use pip anymore because of .certifi

Tags: python, windows, pip

I keep getting an error each time I try to use pip.

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error?

```
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 157, in load_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 469, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 135, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_pip.py", line 35, in apply_patches
    import certifi
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 157, in load_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 469, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 135, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 27, in apply_patches
    generate_pem()
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wincerts.py", line 113, in generate_pem
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(PEM_PATH))
  File "C:\Users\Jiriki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\Jiriki\\AppData\\Local\\.certifi'``
```

Comment: Try to rename the `.certifi` file as a backup (i.e. remove it)? Does the same happen with a venv?

Comment: seems that deleteing the .certifi folder and runing pip --version which remade the folder fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deleting the .certifi folder in appdata/local and the running a pip --version command seemed to refresh the folder and put a missing file into the .certifi folder which in turn fixed the issue. hope this helps anyone who finds this post.